# Add empty rows into a data frame depending ont vector values

Tags: r

I have a vector with two values

v <- c("Sp4","Sp5")

and a data frame such as

```
col1 col2 col3
Sp1 2 2
Sp2 4 6
Sp3 6 4
```

and I would like to add NA at this data frame depending on the vector such as:

```
col1 col2 col3
Sp1 2 2
Sp2 4 6
Sp3 6 4
Sp4 NA NA
SP5 NA NA
```

I tried:

```
for (i in v){
  df1[nrow(df1),] <- i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `bind_rows` after creating 'v' as a `tibble`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   bind_rows(tibble(col1 = v))
#   col1 col2 col3
#1  Sp1    2    2
#2  Sp2    4    6
#3  Sp3    6    4
#4  Sp4   NA   NA
#5  Sp5   NA   NA
```

---

Or with `rbind` from `base R`

```
rbind(df1, data.frame(col1 = v, col2 = NA, col3 = NA))
```